Get a specific JSON value when I have multiple array elements
I have a JSON string that looks like this:
[
    {
        'tagType': 'Author',
        'tagValue': 'Anne Author'
    },
    {
        'tagType': 'Business',
        'tagValue': 'the bidness'
    },
    {
        'tagType': 'Geography',
        'tagValue': 'US'
    },
    {
        'tagType': 'Subscription',
        'tagValue': 'A subscription'
    }
]

For a given tagType (e.g. Geography) how do I get the tagValue (e.g. US)
I've tried various ugly select queries.  I feel there has to be an elegant way to do this
This query (as part of a bigger query) works
[Geography] = (SELECT tagValue 
                            FROM OPENJSON(REPLACE(p.tags, '''', '"')) 
                            WITH (tagType VARCHAR(255) '$.tagType', tagValue VARCHAR(255) '$.tagValue')
                            WHERE tagType = 'Geography')


@DaleK, done.  I've put it in the body of the question

Almost correct with OPENJSON
declare @j nvarchar(max)= N'[{"tagType": "Author", "tagValue": "Anne Author"}, {"tagType": "Business", "tagValue": "the bidness"}, {"tagType": "Geography", "tagValue": "US"}, {"tagType": "Subscription", "tagValue": "A subscription"}]'

SELECT tagType, tagValue
FROM OPENJSON(@j)  
WITH (
    tagType varchar(20),
    tagValue varchar(20)
)
WHERE tagType = 'Geography'

result:



tagType
tagValue




Author
Anne Author


Business
the bidness


Geography
US


Subscription
A subscription



UPDATE:
SELECT tagValue
FROM OPENJSON(@j)  
WITH (
    tagType varchar(20),
    tagValue varchar(20)
)
WHERE tagType = 'Geography'

Result would be: "US"

OK, so what I already had is perfect as I need a specific TagValue for a specific TagType.

i add where condition. and updated answer.

thanks for that.  Sadly, the replace is still needed as I get ' in the string not ".  Thanks for the assist/confirmation

@JoAnywhere - Be sure to adjust the string lengths to accommodate the longest expected tagType and tagValue values. Also, consider NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR if you data might contain characters not supported by VARCHAR.
